# Microsoft Bot Framework - InvalidNeedException, expected Call, have Wait

Tags: c#, asynchronous, botframework

I have been getting an InvalidNeedException in my bot project, but am unable to understand what exactly the exception means.

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidNeedException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=invalid need: expected Call, have Wait
  Source=Microsoft.Bot.Builder
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IWaiter<C>.NextWait[T]()
  InnerException:
```

The following methods all belong to the same Dialog class

```
    [LuisIntent("Test")]
    public async Task GetReleaseTickets(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {            
       await ProcessEntities(context, result.Entities);
       await context.PostAsync("done");
       context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    private async Task ProcessEntities(IDialogContext context, IList<EntityRecommendation> entities) {
        context.Wait<bool>(ProcessX);
        context.Wait<bool>(ProcessY); // exception thrown here
    }
```

Where

```
    public async Task ProcessX(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> argument) {
      //do X
      context.Done();
}

    public async Task ProcessY(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<bool> argument) {
      //do Y
      context.Done();
}
```

It appears I can't call context.Wait twice in a row, but I'm unsure of what the recommended way to call two async methods would be, and want to understand what the "*expected Call, have Wait*" wants me to do. I don't want to call context.Call on that line, just make sure the method completes asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but by looking at the code I think that:

- You don't need to do Context.Wait in the ProcessX/Y methods. The context.Wait is to wait for a message to appear and execute the continuation delegate passed.
- Context.Done is used to 'complete'/'quit' of the current dialog and return a result to the calling dialog and pop the current dialog from the dialog stack. But based on your code it seems that you want to continue listening for messages in the LUIS dialog so I would remove those too.

Comment: Kelsey, did this help?